# What makes us recognize the composer of a song?

Tags: composition, songwriting

Here is the situation: I'm at a friend's house, and he plays a song in the guitar. I never heard it before, but somehow I know it's John Mayer, even though I don't like him very much (I can't even name one song of his).

Based on this kind of situation I have always wondered what is there in a song, that lets us know who composed it, even when another person is playing. Most songs are very "generic", but some have something special, so that my brain tells me who the composer is, but I can't find out why.

So, is it possible to enumerate aspects of a song that might give away its composer? How can I know it and not know why I know? Is it too broad or too subjective to be put down in words?

Comment: Humans are very very good at pattern-recognition. Not perfect, but very good. They like to find patterns, they like to pigeon-hole things with similar patterns. When a pigeon-hole reaches a small enough size, it becomes easy to figure out other things that will fit in it. That's why you hear comments like "Wow! The new Arctic Monkeys song sounds just like Bowie" [It does, btw, but because there are sufficient match-points to be close, even though there are many non-matching points too]

Comment: @Tetsujin These matching points you are talking about, is there a limited set of them in case of music? Or there could be infinite?

Comment: now that's a question... I'd guess almost infinite, because humans can apply finer & finer gradation to pretty much anything. It's more 'general psychology' than music, but look at the current 'need' for people to divide music into smaller & smaller pigeon holes, which I'm sure is a failure to dare listen to anything that doesn't 'fit what I'm supposed to like this week' in case you don't look cool.

Comment: As this is a question about listening to music, it's borderline whether it's more appropriate here or at musicfans.stackexchange.com. I think it's practically impossible to prevent some of our personality from coming through in our work, so music will generally reflect some mix of the composer, the performer(s), and even the engineers and producers. When one person does several of those jobs, the imprint is even deeper.

Comment: It's not just pop music this applies to. If you've listened to Bach, Beethoven, Mahler, et al, there's a good chance you'll guess who may have written another piece you're listening to. Bit like painters (artists).

Comment: @Tim Yes, exactly!

Comment: @coconochao Yes, the set of *dimensions* of similarity between musical compositions is not too large - it's basically all those things that music theory is about. For instance, there was an infamous German duo in the 80s with literally a dozen hits reusing the exact same chord progressions. (Usually it's a *bit* more subtle than that.)

Comment: The show segment "The Piano Puzzler" is premised on this very idea.  The guy takes a well known tune and rewrites it in the style of a famous classical composer.  The game is to guess the tune and the composer.  That's fun unto itself, but then the question is asked, "What makes this in the style of [...]" and they discuss, that makes it enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

An artist's musical signature is comprised of the patterns they typically use in melody, harmony, rhythm and every other aspect of music.

This might shed some light:

[What contributes to an artist's melodic "signature?"](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64176/what-contributes-to-an-artists-melodic-signature/70304#70304)

Comment: Does anybody care to comment on why this answer was downvoted? I can't learn if you don't provide feedback.